# How to access array value inside PromiseValue?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native, promise

I'm new to React-Redux. I am making an api call to a json file and would like to return the contents of this file as an array. I haven't dealt with Promises very much, so my knowledge of accessing them is a little foggy. Basically, there's what I have:

```
  const fetchData = () => {
   return fetch('endpoint.json')
    .then(results => results.json())
    }

getProducts: (cb, timeout) => setTimeout(() => cb(fetchData().then(response => response)), timeout || TIMEOUT)
```

getProducts currently returns the following, which I can open up to look at in the console:

```
action {type: "RECEIVE_PRODUCTS", products: Promise}
products: Promise
__proto__ :Promise
[[PromiseStatus]] :"resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]: Array(3)
```

How can I access the PromiseValue? I need to get the JSON array directly!

Comment: do another `then`

Comment: *getProducts currently returns the following* it shouldn't return that ... it should return what `setTimeout` returns ... a number

Comment: `response` is the JSON you want - it will only ever be available asyncrhonously - contrary to Isaac's suggestion, another `.then` won't change anything ... unless you use `.then` inside your callback of course. Also `.then(response => response)` is pointless, geet rid of it

Answer (score 2):

After a <strike>heated</strike> discussion, it has been suggested that you rewrite your `getProducts` method to be more Promise-like. Don't mix callbacks with promises, put your code inside the `then` methods. Chain promises where you can.

---

Either of these solutions described here should suffice

You have to write your `getProducts` inside a `then`

```
fetchData().then((jsonResults)=> {
  // put the code surrounding getProducts here
  return {
    getProducts: jsonResults
  }
})
```

Or, you could use `await` (see [async functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)):

```
let products = await fetchData();
return {
  getProducts: products
}
```

---

Example

```
> console.log(Promise.resolve([1,2,3]))
Promise {<resolved>: Array(3)}
__proto__: Promise
  [[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"
  [[PromiseValue]]: Array(3)

> Promise.resolve([1,2,3]).then((jsonResults) => {
  console.log(jsonResults);
})
(3) [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: So sorry ... confused `fetchData` with `getProducts` ... me so dumb :p removing comments as we speaqk, sorry for MY confusion

Comment: Yea thought that was the case. I'm suggesting here he rewrite `getProducts` in favour of the convoluted callback method

Comment: callbacks + promises == confusion :p (mine)

Comment: It's cool, editing answer to outline the recommended approach

Comment: thank you @Isaac. I think your edits are great, but the only thing is, I need to be able to access getProducts outside of this file as an expected function. Is there anyway I can get getProducts as its own function, separated from fetchData?

Comment: @Leia_Organa your `getProducts` will need to return a promise. Try to follow this guide: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/02/16/how-javascript-promises-work/

Answer (score -1):

You can use await or you can return the promise and handle the callback

reference : https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/279898/how-do-i-make-a-javascript-promise-return-something-other-than-a-promise